# Which jar has org.apache.hadoop.lib.input.FileSplit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to use the following command but it said I need to import org.apache.hadoop.lib.input.FileSplit. I tried to googled online but still have no idea which jar I should import. The jars I already imported are commons-cli-1.2.jar, hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar and hadoop-mapreduce-clienr-core-2.8.0.jar.

```
// Get the direction of the file and the name           
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
file = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxz7x.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Wen

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;` is the solution.